# What is the idiomatic way of processing a scope value in an AngularJS directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm not quite sure how to do this. Basically I have a custom message directive (as an element) that has a couple of fields in its scope, among them the **content** field containing its text. The text can contain URLs (beginning with http/https) and hashtags (beginning with # and space delimited).

What is an idiomatic way of processing $scope.content so that all the links and hashtags are transformed into hyperlinks?

Comment: Check the `linky` filter: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize.filter:linky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "transformed into hyperlinks", but suppose you split the contents into array of strings. Than you can append it to the element in the linking function:

```
link: function($scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller) {
    var links = iElem.text().split(",");
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        iElem.append("<a href='" + links[i] + "'>" + links[i] + "</a>");
    };
    $compile(iElm.contents())($scope);
}
```

For the append function I suggest to use Underscote [template](http://underscorejs.org/#template) function instead:

```
var linkTemplate = _.template('<a href="<%= link %>"><%= link %></a>');
```

and then inside the loop call

```
linkTemplate(links[i]);
```

Comment: Although it's not what I did, instead using a filter, it's a fair method (not as idiomatic though).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve this is using directives due to angular's $sce (strict contextual escaping) and binding of html.

Here's how I would go about it:

```
angular.module('myModule').directive('content', function () {
  return {
    scope: {
      text: '@'
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var urlRegex = /((https?|ftp):\/\/(-\.)?([^\s\/?\.#-]+\.?)+(\/[^\s]*)?$)/g,
          urlReplacer = '<a href="\$1">\$1</a>',
          hashtagRegex = /#([0-9A-z_]*[A-z_]+[A-z0-9]*)/g,
          hashtagReplacer = '<a href="https://twitter.com/search/?q=%23\$1">#\$1</a>';

      scope.$watch('text', function (n) {
        if (n && n.length) {
          var parsed = n.replace(urlRegex, urlReplacer);
          parsed = parsed.replace(hashtagRegex, hashtagReplacer);
          element.html(parsed); 
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```